# Как передать событие клик на другой элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(document).on("click", ".tabs_arrow", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass("left_tabs_arrow")) {
    $(".mCSB_buttonLeft").trigger("click");
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass("right_tabs_arrow")) {
    $(".mCSB_buttonRight").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs_arrows">
  <button type="button" class="tabs_arrow left_tabs_arrow">left</button>
  <button type="button" class="tabs_arrow right_tabs_arrow">right</button>
</div>
<div class="chart_tabs_scrollbar">
 <a href="#" class="mCSB_buttonLeft"></a>
 <a href="#" class="mCSB_buttonRight"></a>
</div>
```

В `.chart_tabs_scrollbar` есть кнопки для прокрутки скролбара плагина. Но событие клик на них не передается. Как правильно это сделать?
Использую плагин mCustomScrollbar. Вот его страница [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось стрелки плагина перенести в блок .tabs_arrows.

```
   leftArrow = $(".mCSB_buttonLeft");
   rightArrow = $(".mCSB_buttonRight");
   leftArrow.appendTo(".tabs_arrows");
   rightArrow.appendTo(".tabs_arrows");
```